# React. почему не могу вставить компонент из сторонней библиотеки?

Tags: reactjs

Имею последнюю версию react react@17.0.1 и использую библиотеку react-player, импортирую плеер, вставляю в верстку и получаю ошибки:

> ------- Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>
> ------- VM30105 react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the
>  component:  at Provider
> (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js:14:20)
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
> handling behavior.
>
> ------- Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
> application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
> in a useEffect cleanup function.

Мой код:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { rootReducer } from "../redux/rootReducer.js";

import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'


import { compose, createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    )
);

const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);

function App() {
   
    return (
        <div>
          
            <ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' />
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

if (document.getElementById("app")) {
    ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("app"));
}
```

Comment: Как только я убираю обертку <Provider store={store}> ***  </Provider> все хорошо работает, в чем может быть проблема, также когда пытаюсь добавить функциональные компоненты созданные мною, возникает та же ошибка.

Comment: Можете воспроизвести вашу проблему на codesandbox.io?